# How do I create true two-color images in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I want to create a file with 1 bit color-depth, i.e. one bit per pixel. Which file formats are suitable for that, and how do I do this in GIMP?

This is for self-created checkerboard for subsequent experiments with image analysis and modification.

Thank you.

PS: I know about [How to convert color images to black & white in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69308/how-to-convert-color-images-to-black-white-in-gimp) but if I store this as JPG or PNG, there are still gray pixels included.

Comment: BMP is most likely the format you need.

Comment: Most formats except for JPEG should do, actually. The important part is that the image has to have only two colors when the export happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In GIMP click *Image > Mode > Indexed*

Select the option which says "*Use Black and White (1 bit) palette*"

Click *File > Export As*

Give your file a new new name, and end with the file extension .BMP and hit *Export* - if a warning comes up about transparency not being supported in bitmap, ignore it, and hit OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need and acheved it by exporting as PNG. This generates a true 1 bit depth image.